# How to change multiple attribute values from collection of elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a collection of elements using IEnumerable

and this is my XML file

```
<string name="whatever" />
<string name="whatever" />
<string name="whatever" />
```

I want to change the values (whatever) of attributes that are called name.

```
<string name="whatever2" />
<string name="whatever2" />
<string name="whatever2" />
```

something like this

This is what I currently have for my collection of elements

```
XElement elements = XElement.Load(file);  
IEnumerable<XElement> inlink = 
from el in elements.Elements()
where (string)el.Attribute("name").Value == "whatever"
select el;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the collection of XElement for which you need to change the attribute, you could use [XElement.SetAttributeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=netframework-4.8) method for assinging new values to attributes. For example,

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);  
var nodeList= root.Elements().Where(x=>(string)x.Attribute("name").Value == "whatever");
foreach(var node in nodeList)
{
    node.SetAttributeValue("name","whatever2");
}
```